# Issue with Chained Payment Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using chained payments in [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) and getting the following error when placing a transaction:

```
Unable to process due to payment error
The fee payer PRIMARYRECEIVER can only be used if a primary receiver is specified
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this parameter to indicate your primary receiver , in order to you the fees payer as PRIMARYRECEIVER.

Please try with that

receiverList.receiver(n).primary

Set to true to indicate a chained payment; only one receiver can be a primary receiver. Omit this field, or set it to false for simple and parallel payments.

Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/